# SwiftUI - How to pass data from childView's viewModel to parentView's viewModel?

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-view

I have SwiftUI view1, with its viewModel1.
view1 has a child view view2 with viewModel2.
How can I pass a data for viewModel2 to viewModel1?
Thanks!

Comment: Please read this [mcve]. To answer your question, you can use delegate pattern, closures or combine framework.

Comment: How can I solve it with combine? I don't know how can I subscribe for parent's view viewModel to child's view viewModel published data?

Comment: We don't use view model objects in SwiftUI you have to learn how the View struct works

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple ways you can achieve this. For example you can use binding if you want a variable in model1 and model2 to always be the same.

You could pass a callback from view1 to view2?

```
struct view2: View {
    var delegate: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View { 
    // REST OF CODE

struct view1: View {
    
    var body: some View { 
    view2(delegate: {
        // Something that can modify viewModel1 or do something with data or ....
    })
 // REST OF CODE
```

When you create viewModel2, create weak reference to viewmodel1? create a delegate for viewModel2 and let viewmodel1 subscribe?